# Combination of wrapping component inside function, event handling and state hook behaves unexpectedly

Tags: reactjs

This combination of factors results in unexpected behaviour:

- returning a child component from a function in a parent component
- having an onClick listener inside child component update its own state through a hook call
- having that same listener call an event listener that updates parent state

I made an example at codesandbox.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kepler-bur5h

```
const ChildComponent = ({ onClick, title }) => {
  const [isButtonClicked, setIsButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="childComponent">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ isButtonClicked }, null, 2)}</pre>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsButtonClicked(true);
          onClick();
        }}
      >
        button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(true);
  const WrappedChildComponent = () => (
    <ChildComponent
      title="wrapped child"
      onClick={() => {
        setValue(!value);
      }}
    />
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>parent</h2>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ value }, null, 2)}</pre>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(true)}>reset value</button>
      <div>
        <ChildComponent
          title="child"
          onClick={() => {
            setValue(!value);
          }}
        />
        <WrappedChildComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `WrappedChildComponent` doesn't update its own `isButtonClicked` when button is clicked, whereas the normal `ChildComponent` does.

I would expect the wrapped component to behave similar to the normal child component.

What causes this behaviour?

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, you're saying that your `WrappedChildComponent` doesn't get the new `value` from the `parent` component when it changes?

Comment: @goto1 the `WrappedChildComponent` doesn't update its own `isButtonClicked` when button is clicked. `value` is not passed to `WrappedChildComponent`

Comment: Oh ok, I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, you need to use the `useEffect` hook to create your `WrappedChildComponent`:

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(true)
  const [wrappedChildComponent, setWrappedChildComponent] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setWrappedChildComponent(
      <ChildComponent
        title="wrapped child"
        onClick={() => { setValue(!value) }
      />
    )

  // IMPORTANT: put `value` (since that what it depends on) 
  // in your dependency array so you don't 
  // get an infinite loop (rendering forever)
  }, [value])

  return (
    <div> 
      ...
      <div>
        <ChildComponent
          title="child"
          onClick={() => { setValue(!value); }} 
        />
        {wrappedChildComponent}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

This fixes the issue of `isButtonClicked` inside of `WrappedComponent` not being able to set its own state. The way you had it, `WrappedComponent` is getting cached essentially inside of `App`, so you need to create an additional hook to be able to handle this situation properly.

Also, if you were relying on the `value` state from `App` inside of your `WrappedComponent` then you'd also be seeing a strange behavior (`value` from `App` not updating inside of `WrappedComponent`), at least the way you had it initially. The above solution takes care of both.

Here's a link to the demo:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-mcclintock-4le2e?fontsize=14)

Comment: That explains it. Thanks!

Comment: Explanation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 0):

I defined the function outside the app and it worked as expected. This is the updated code. [Check the sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-johnson-q9175)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const ChildComponent = ({ onClick, title }) => {
  const [isButtonClicked, setIsButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="childComponent">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ isButtonClicked }, null, 2)}</pre>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsButtonClicked(true);
          onClick();
        }}
      >
        button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const WrappedChildComponent = ({assignValue}) => (
  <ChildComponent
    title="wrapped child"
    onClick={() => {
      assignValue(false);
    }}
  />
);
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>parent</h2>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ value }, null, 2)}</pre>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(true)}>reset value</button>
      <div>
        <ChildComponent
          title="child"
          onClick={() => {
            setValue(false);
          }}
        />
        <WrappedChildComponent assignValue={(e)=> setValue(e)}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This works around the problem but does not solve it entirely.
The reason for wrapping the child component in a function could be: not having to assign the callback to each instance. The method you propose still requires that.